# Loading message Jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile

I am developing a mobile application using jquery mobile. Whenever the `showPageLoadingMsg()` called, it executes the below `".ui-loader"` class. But, instead I want to load the external image. Is  it possible?

```
.ui-loader { display: none; position: absolute; opacity: .85; image:url('img/loader.gif'); z-index: 100; left: 50%; width: 200px; margin-left: -130px; margin-top: -35px; padding: 10px 30px; }
```

Help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What external image are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

Use `background-image:url('img/loader.gif');`